# Ajax Post with express js get req parameter error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using the ajax to post the data from javascript front end to express js has backend server. How i can get the posted data, in express js api method req params. I am facing issue when i try to parse the request data below is my code.Please help me to solve this

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/api/save_user/",
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                data: { name: 'Justin', number: '662***' },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var resp = JSON.parse(response)

                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
```

> Express Js server side

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path')
const os = require('os');
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())


//deploy the smart contract
app.post('/api/save_user', (req, res) => {
    console.log((JSON.parse(req.body)));
    res.send({})
})
```

> Error Log

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158:10)
    at parse (/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
```

Comment: Whats the output of  `log.console(response)`

Comment: add line in express before route `app.use(express.json({
  type: ['application/json', 'text/plain']
}))
` and try again

Comment: i am facing issue  console.log((JSON.parse(req.body))); in server side express js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that jquery expect you to pass an string with the json inside. try like this:

```js
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/api/save_user/",
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                data: JSON.stringify({ name: 'Justin', number: '662***' }),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var resp = JSON.parse(response)

                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: still same, I am facing the issue.

Comment: this worked, but I need to remove JSON.parse in express js server-side

Comment: This line `app.use(bodyParser.json())`, make the parse of all requests and responses.